How do I test the values used to instantiate an aws client?
I am updating a class typescript module to start using v3 of the aws-sdk.
In one of the methods I have the lines:
    const eventBridgeClient = new EventBridgeClient({ region: this.region })
    const kmsClient = new KMSClient({ region: this.region })

Where region is set from config used to instantiate the class.
For this reason when I want the unit testing to ensure the region is passing through correctly.
I am using the aws-sdk-client-mock and aws-sdk-client-mock-jest library to mock the aws-sdk code during the unit testing.  Unfortunately I have not been able to fathom a way to determine what was use to instantiate the above methods.
I can spy on the method with jest.spyon if I mock the module but then my mocking fails for testing commands sent.
    Expected EventBridgeClient to receive "DescribeRuleCommand" with {"Name": "test-rule-1"}
    EventBridgeClient received matching "DescribeRuleCommand" 0 times

    Calls:
      1. DescribeRuleCommand: undefined
      2. ListTargetsByRuleCommand: undefined
      3. PutTargetsCommand: undefined
      4. PutRuleCommand: undefined

(Test passes with I do not mock the client module.)
It seems like a trivial problem but every attempt (apart from the complete mocking of the client library.)  Causes me to be unable to test the part.
I suspect it would be possible to solve this by completely mocking the client library but it seems an overly complex solution for a minor ask.

The following worke for me though I would like to think there is a more straight forward answer
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-kms', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@aws-sdk/client-kms')

  const moduleObject = {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    KMSClient: jest.fn(),
  }
  moduleObject.KMSClient.prototype = originalModule.KMSClient.prototype
  return moduleObject
})
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge')

  const moduleObject = {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    EventBridgeClient: jest.fn(),
  }
  moduleObject.EventBridgeClient.prototype = originalModule.EventBridgeClient.prototype
  return moduleObject
})

const eventbridgeClientMock = mockClient(EventBridgeClient)
const kmsClientMock = mockClient(KMSClient)

I can then use eventbridgeClientMock for mocking the commands sent to the client as per normal for `import { mockClient } from 'aws-sdk-client-mock'
But I can now get the constructor calls e.g.
expect(EventBridgeClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ region: 'us-east-1' })

